# MathJax not rendering latex when nested in html

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, mathjax

I have this type of formula nested with html:

```
<div><p>$$</p></div>
<div><p> a, b \in \mathbb{R}, then applies (a+b)^{2} = a^{2} + ab + b^{2} </p></div>
<div><p>$$</p></div>
```

And this does not render. However when its all on one line it does, like this:

```
<div><p>$$ a, b \in \mathbb{R}, then applies (a+b)^{2} = a^{2} + ab + b^{2} $$ </p></div>
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
    window.MathJax = {
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\[","\]"] ],
       displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
       processEnvironments: true,
      processEscapes: true
    },
                MathML: {
                    extensions: ['content-mathml.js']
                },
                // Center justify equations in code and markdown cells. Elsewhere
                // we use CSS to left justify single line equations in code cells.
                displayAlign: 'center',
                "HTML-CSS": {
                    availableFonts: [],
                    imageFont: null,
                    preferredFont: null,
                    webFont: "STIX-Web",
                    styles: {'.MathJax_Display': {"margin": 0}},
                    linebreaks: { automatic: true }
                },
  };
</script>

<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe">
</script>
```

Any suggestions as to why this may not be working are very welcome.
Thanks for looking

Comment: MathJax stops TeX extraction at HTML tag boundaries (except for br and wbr tags), cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents.